# why is the following code violating The Law of Demeter?

Tags: coding-style

```
final String outputDir = ctxt.getOptions().getScratchDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

where Law of Demeter says that a method f of a class C should only call the methods of these:

- C
- An object created by f
- An object passed as an argument to f
- An object held in an instance variable of C

Comment: That has to be about the worst 'Law' I've ever seen .. :} Anyway, ["an object should avoid invoking methods of a member object returned by another method."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). How to avoid this violation or 'improve' the code without making it needlessly more complex or just shoving the violation elsewhere .. I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Calling getScratchDir() on the instance of the Options class is the violation here.

Now, to improve the architecture we need to know more about what the code tries to do. Could the method be moved into the CTxt class?